# Why to create a derived password of 256 bytes and later get bytes from result?

Tags: c#, aes

I have found an example that uses AES encrypt to encrypt text. The code is this:

```
public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string Password,
    string Salt = "Kosher", string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1",   
    int PasswordIterations = 2, string InitialVector = "OFRna73m*aze01xY",    
    int KeySize = 256)    
{    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlainText))    
        return "";

    byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);    
    byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);    
    byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);    
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);    
    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);    
    RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();    
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;    
    byte[] CipherTextBytes = null;    
    using (ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes))    
    {    
        using (MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream())    
        {    
            using (CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))    
            {    
                CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);    
                CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();    
                CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();    
                MemStream.Close();    
                CryptoStream.Close();    
            }    
        }    
    }

    SymmetricKey.Clear();    
    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
}
```

My question is: how is the key for the AES algorithm generated? These 2 lines:

```
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);

    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
```

First, it creates a derived key of 256 bytes, and later, create a key getting pseudo random bytes of this derived key. It has to be divided by 8 because the AES algorithm need 128, 182 or 256 bits, not bytes. In this case, how derived key is 256 bytes, the key for AES will be 256 bits.

But why does it do that? Wouldn't it better create the derived key with the needed length, not 256 bytes but 256 bits (256 bytes / 8)? So It wouldn't be needed to create a new key taken the 1/8 bytes of the derived key.

Also, the getBytes() method, in the description of the method, it says it returns pseudo-random key bytes. So doesn't it do the AES key would be different in each case? How to generate again the AES key from decryption if it is pseudo random key bytes?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. It's creating the `PasswordDerivedBytes` with all the information it's got, and then asking for `KeySize / 8` bytes to be generated from that info. Presumably `KeySize` is meant to be in bits, but `PasswordDerivedBytes.GetBytes` is in bytes. (It doesn't help that a lot of this code is unconventional, particularly in terms of the parameter/variable names - you might want to find another example.)

Comment: Note: you should use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` as `PasswordDeriveBytes` is obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, it creates a derived key of 256 bytes

Where? I don't see any 256-byte key being created.

> and later, create a key getting pseudo random bytes of this derived key. It has to be divided by 8 because the AES algorithm need 128, 182 or 256 bits, not bytes

Yes, the function input of `KeySize` (which should be `keySize` by normal C# naming conventions) is in bits, but `GetBytes` wants an input in bytes.  `x / 8` is one of the three right answers for that conversion (`(x + 7) / 8` is another, and `x & 7 == 0 ? x / 8 : throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x))` is the third)

> But why does it do that? Wouldn't it better create the derived key with the needed length, not 256 bytes but 256 bits (256 bytes / 8)? So It wouldn't be needed to create a new key taken the 1/8 bytes of the derived key.

It would be good to do that.  But since it is already doing that, there's no "better" to be had.

> Also, the getBytes() method, in the description of the method, it says it returns pseudo-random key bytes. So doesn't it do the AES key would be different in each case? How to generate again the AES key from decryption if it is pseudo random key bytes?

<sub>I have to make a pedantic point: There is no `getBytes` method.  C# is a case-sensitive language, and the method name is `GetBytes`.</sub>

[pseudorandom](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pseudorandom): noting or pertaining to random numbers generated by a definite computational process to satisfy a statistical test.

`PasswordDeriveBytes` is an implementation of `PBKDF1` (except it continues beyond the limits of PBKDF1), which is a deterministic algorithm.  Given the same inputs (password, seed, iteration count, pseudo-random function (hash algorithm)) the same output is produced.  Change any of the inputs slightly, and the output is significantly different.

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (an implementation of `PBKDF2`) is also a deterministic, but chaotic, algorithm.

So you produce the same answer again in either of them (but not across them) by giving all the same inputs.

When using password-based encryption (PKCS#5) the flow is

- Pick a PRF
- Pick an iteration count
- Generate a random salt
- Write down these choices
- Apply these three things, plus the password to generate a key
- Encrypt the data
- Write down to the encrypted data

When decrypting one

- Read the PRF
- Read the iteration count
- Read the salt
- Apply these three things, plus the password to generate a key
- Read the encrypted data
- Decrypt it
- Party on

---

While this code is doing that part right, the IV and Salt should not be ASCII (or UTF8) strings, they should be "just bytes" (`byte[]`).  If they need to be transported as strings then they should be base64, or some other "arbitrary" [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).